# Drawing a Hexagon with UIBezierPath (point first)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw a Hexagon using UIBezierPath and ZEPolygon, it works great but my hexagon is flat on top. I have tried everything to get it to draw form a point in the middle including a 180 degree transform on the path which work but everything else break.

[This is how it looks now](http://postimg.org/image/wndnt77ah/)

[This is how i would like it to look](http://postimg.org/image/9z3egyzjl/)

My code is below

```
UIImageView *maskedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];

UIBezierPath *nonagon = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithPolygonInRect:maskedImageView.frame numberOfSides:6];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = nonagon.CGPath;

maskedImageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;

[self.view addSubview:maskedImageView];
```

[This is the library i used for the drawing the bezier path](https://github.com/ZevEisenberg/ZEPolygon)

Thanks for any help

Comment: 180 degree transform? Wouldn't you want 90?

Comment: Sorry yes, 90 degrees is correct but the offset are all incorrect and the image underneath is no where to be seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate a UIBezierPath with a CGTransform, it will be rotated around the point (0,0), and for your path the point (0,0) is the top left corner of your shape. This is why the offset is incorrect when you just rotate by 90 degrees w/o doing anything else - its rotating around the wrong point.

So before you rotate, you need to center the path to the point (0,0), then rotate it, then move it back so that (0,0) is at its top left.

the following code will rotate the polygon 90 degrees:

```
// get the size of the image, we'll need this for our path and for later too
CGRect boundsForPoly = maskedImageView.frame;
// create our path inside the rect
UIBezierPath *nonagon = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithPolygonInRect:boundsForPoly numberOfSides:6];
// center the polygon on (0,0)
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-boundsForPoly.size.width/2, -boundsForPoly.size.height/2)];
// rotate it 90 degrees
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
// now move it back so that the top left of its bounding box is (0,0)
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(nonagon.bounds.size.width/2, nonagon.bounds.size.height/2)];
```

this will rotate the polygon 90 degrees, and keep it's top left corner at (0,0)

The blue outline is your path before, and the green outline is after the rotation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the answer from adam.wulf is with the line

> [nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(nonagon.bounds.size.width/2, nonagon.bounds.size.height/2)];

It doesn't center the polygon to the center of the frame. It should be instead

```
//Centered version
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(boundsForPoly.size.width/2, boundsForPoly.size.height/2/2)];
```

Thus the code should look like following from adam.wulf

```
// get the size of the image, we'll need this for our path and for later too
CGRect boundsForPoly = maskedImageView.frame;
// create our path inside the rect
UIBezierPath *nonagon = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithPolygonInRect:boundsForPoly numberOfSides:6];
// center the polygon on (0,0)
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-boundsForPoly.size.width/2, -boundsForPoly.size.height/2)];
// rotate it 90 degrees
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
// now move it back so that the top left of its bounding box is (0,0)
[nonagon applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(boundsForPoly.size.width/2, boundsForPoly.size.height/2/2)];
```